# Getting REST Resource path in EAR file

Tags: java, rest, jakarta-ee, ejb, jax-rs

I have an EJB project which contains a Rest Web Service EJB. I package this EJB.jar project into an EAR file along with a WAR project. What would be the absolute path of my Rest Web Service then?

Comment: It depends on the server name and the context that ear/war file is deployed under.

Comment: @hooknc Could you provide an example? Like localhost:8080/?/?. I'm using Glassfish 4.

Comment: I haven't worked with EAR files directly.  But from what I just read, the "context-root" is set in your EAR's configuration.  So here is the best url that I'll be able to give you http://localhost:8080/<context-root>/<url-to-rest-resource>.  If you determine that your context-root is blank or empty, then your application will be deployed in the root context and your url will look close to: http://localhost:8080/<url-to-rest-resource>.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My problem seems to be due to the fact that the EJB JAR file containing the EJB REST Web Service is packaged in an EAR file alongside a WAR file. I've read that you can use JAX-RS within an EJB JAR file but what I wasn't aware of was that this JAR file has to then be packaged within the WEB-INF/lib folder in a Dynamic Web Project (WAR file). [According to this link,](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSCKBL_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.nd.multiplatform.doc/ae/twbs_jaxrs_ejb_nointerface.html) it is not supported for JAX-RS EJB's to be included in an EAR file.

Comment: indeed, JAX-RS annotated enterprise beans are **not supported** in a separate ejb-jar file that is included in an EAR.

Comment: Is this still valid? I am facing the sample problem, ejb and war are deployed separately.

Answer (score 1):

Glad that you've already found an answer.
From my perspective, exposing stateless EJB beans as restfull services is fast, but typically isn't the best approach.

Usually, it is better to create restfull endpoint classes in a web module that wraps errors/ exceptions coming from ejb services. This is also a good place to do some translations etc.